# Get Class in JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

In a JPA application, Bill class has been extended to BilledBill, CancelledBill and RefundBill.

There is a JPQL query which list category name, item name, etc, as followed.

```
        String jpql = "select c.name, i.name, count(bi.bill), sum(bf.feeValue), bf.fee.feeType "
            + " from BillFee bf join bf.billItem bi join bi.item i join i.category c  "
            + " where bi.bill.institution=:ins "
            + " and bi.item.department.institution=:ins "
            + " and  bi.bill.billType= :bTp  "
            + " and  bi.bill.createdAt between :fromDate and :toDate "
            + " and (bi.bill.paymentMethod = :pm1 "
            + " or  bi.bill.paymentMethod = :pm2 "
            + " or  bi.bill.paymentMethod = :pm3 "
            + " or  bi.bill.paymentMethod = :pm4)"
            + " group by i.name, c.name, bf.fee.feeType "
            + " order by c.name, i.name, bf.fee.feeType";

    temMap.put("toDate", toDate);
    temMap.put("fromDate", fromDate);
    temMap.put("ins", institution);
    temMap.put("bTp", BillType.OpdBill);
    temMap.put("pm1", PaymentMethod.Cash);
    temMap.put("pm2", PaymentMethod.Card);
    temMap.put("pm3", PaymentMethod.Cheque);
    temMap.put("pm4", PaymentMethod.Slip);

    List<Object[]> lobjs = getBillFacade().findAggregates(jpql, temMap, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

I want to group by the class and get the class in the select statement. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `discriminator column` then it is possible.

Let's assume your discriminator column is `String` field named `DTYPE`. You should add to your entities:

```
@Column(name = "DTYPE")
private String clazz;
// ..
// getter
```

Now you can use it in your `JPQL Query`:

```
String jpql = "select c.name, i.name, bill.clazz // .. rest of the query
```